# Difficulty overwriting log file ONLY at start of program

Tags: python

I've searched around quite a bit and I've found some similar questions but none of the answers have helped with my situation. I set up my logging with a python dictionary like so

```
LOG_DICT = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fileHandler': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'mode': 'w',
            'filename': 'C:\\Users\\Sam\\Documents\\Shoe Stuff\\MonitorV2\\logs\\Monitor.log'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # root logger
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['fileHandler'],
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code in my main program,

```
logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_DICT)
logger = logging.getLogger('')
```

along with the import of this dictionary since it is stored in its own module. In my other modules, I simply do this in my base class

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and use `self.logger.info()` or `self.logger.debug()`, etc.

My issue (I guess it does make sense), is that I'm overwriting the log file each time I instantiate a new logger instance with `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, and that's because I have set the mode in my `fileHandler` to `'w'`. I would like for the log file to be erased on the start of each program run and not appended every time. Is there a way I can do this so I can log each module to the same log file without overwriting during the program's run?

Would I have to create a new file handler with mode set to append and add separate loggers for each module in my logging dictionary config? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: A quick and dirty fix is just using a with open statement in my main.py with write permissions. I feel like there should be a built in way with logging or a better way with logging multiple modules to accomplish what I am setting out to do though.

Comment: Maybe you can name your logger, not propagate it (`'propagate': False`) and call always the same logger (`self.logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")`)...